Динамический массив функций
Решил для развлечения быстро накатать подобие консольного Exel со своим блэкджеком и алкоголем.
Хотел реализовать прикол, что ты сам свои функции обработки пишешь и понял, что хз как это сделать. Была идея сделать типо тако-го
void (*func[3])(); //Статически работает
void (*(*functions))() = new (*void())[amountOfFunctions]; //Динамически не работает
Но понял что это не сильно работает.
Кто знает, можно ли такое реализовать без include-ов?
Если да, то как это работает? (Ну и как выглядит)

Не понято, что именно Вы ожидаете. Какое ожидаемое поведение Вы хотите во второй строке? (void (*(*functions))() = new (*void())[amountOfFunctions];)

А зачем вам вообще new, когда есть std::vector?

На первый вопрос:
Ну как мы обычно создаём динамический массив?
(указатель на тип данных) имя = new (тип данных)[количество];
Тут хотел так-же
А на второй.
Я Просто напросто ненавижу чужие библиотеки и стараюсь писать на том, что изначально предоставляет язык. Пока я учусь, это помогает мне понять всякие детали и тонкости процессов.

@RiabchenkoNikita библиотека std является частью стандарта языка с++. Очень рекомендую разбираться как раз с неё. Реализация стандартных классов - это дух языка. Используйте std, Чего не понимаете - просто используйте, постепенно разбираясь почему и что именно так, как оно есть.

Если уже есть объявленные прототипы нужныхъ функций, то вместо дополнительных объявлений и фокусов со скобочками брать тип от прототипов посредством decltype:
#include <vector>

void f1() { ... }
void f2() { ... }

int main()
{
    ::std::vector<decltype(&f1)> funcs{};
    funcs.emplace_back(&f1);
    funcs.emplace_back(&f2);
}


Это всё хорошо, но присутствует #include . В вопросе я хотел узнать, как создать динамический массив, а не vector<>

@RiabchenkoNikita vector это и есть динамический массив. У массива, созданного при помощи оператора new размер фиксируется во время создания. Хотя ничего не мешает использовать предложенный тут метод для вызова оператор new.

Я понмю как реализован класс vector. Просто, как бы это описать, ты понимаешь как оно там внутри работает очень абстрактно и не можешь повторить этот класс vector самостоятельно. Я просто очень сильно ненавижу "Магию" в программировании. Типо, оно работает с помощью Иисуса и даже не думай об этом.

Просто дополняя ответ Halturin Evgeniy — можно и без using + auto. Например:
std::cout << "\ndynamic\n";
void(**functions_2)() = new (void(*[amountOfFunctions])()){ f1, f2, f3 };
for (size_t i = 0; i < amountOfFunctions; ++i) {

Вот, все компилируется и работает: https://ideone.com/MyMBPh

так вооот куда эти скобки [] ставить new (void(*[amountOfFunctions])())

Compilation failed due to following error(s).main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:23:59: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘)’ token
23 |     void(**functions_2)() = new (void(*[amountOfFunctions])()){ f1, f2, f3 };
Это мне выдают некоторые компиляторы. Взял с онлайн одного эту ошибку (там хорошо расписывают).

Можно конкретнее о компиляторах? Просто даже интересно, где они там лямбду видят :)

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler
Часто использую его когда в транспорте. быстро и +- удобно. Права сложные ошибки как ты видишь обрабатывает через попу

@RiabchenkoNikita в Вашей ссылке нет ни каких ошибок. И никаких лямбд не видно ни в вашем вопросе, ни в наших ответах, ни, опять же, в Вашей ссылке. SO это не место, где занимаются гаданием. Конкретизируйте вопрос, приводите код с ошибкой, описывайте задачу подробнее, но не ждите, что другие просто догадаются, что Вы имели в виду.

Если я правильно понял задачу
#include <iostream>

void f1() { std::cout << "do f1\n"; }
void f2() { std::cout << "do f2\n"; }
void f3() { std::cout << "do f3\n"; }

using func_t = void (*)();
using func_p = func_t*;

int main()
{
    const int amountOfFunctions = 3;

    std::cout << "static\n";
    //void (*functions_1[amountOfFunctions])() = { f1, f2, f3 };
    func_t functions_1[] = { f1, f2, f3 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < amountOfFunctions; ++i) {
        functions_1[i]();
    }

    std::cout << "\ndynamic\n";
    //func_t* functions_2 = new func_t[amountOfFunctions]{f1, f2, f3};
    auto functions_2 = new func_t[amountOfFunctions]{ f1, f2, f3 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < amountOfFunctions; ++i) {
        functions_2[i]();
    }
    delete[] functions_2;

    std::cout << "\n\n   press [Enter]...";
    std::cin.get();
}

В общем, using + auto Вам в помощь.
Но, к сожалению, это навряд ли поможет в контексте

сам свои функции обработки пишешь


Ошибки, Ошибки и ошибки. Я хочу что-то наподобие такого
int number = 10;
void* funcs = new void*()[number];
funcs[1] = {...};

@RiabchenkoNikita педставленный код компилируется без ошибок

@RiabchenkoNikita посмотрите std::function

Почитал, приольно. Хочеться просто ручками всё это потрогать а не с помощью уже готовых методов.
Типо сам создал указатель, сам выделил память, сам заполнил и дальше уже играешся.

@RiabchenkoNikita посмотрите как это реализовано, изучите. Потом закройте чужой код и повторите всё сами. Чем не способ?
